# error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test to Annotation

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am newbie to junit Mockito framework, I have mocked the Dependency Injection using powermock framework, but I am getting error in eclipse on `@Test` annotation the error is **"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Test to Annotation"**

```
package org.singh.util.MockitoDemo;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doNothing;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;

import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ExampleUtil.class, ExamplePojo.class})
public class ExamplePojoTest{

    @Test
    public void testMethodMakingPrivateMethodCall() throws Exception {
        ExamplePojo spyExamplePojo = PowerMockito.spy(new ExamplePojo());
        when(spyExamplePojo, method(ExamplePojo.class, "privateMethod", String.class)).withArguments(anyString()).thenReturn("test test");
        String result = spyExamplePojo.methodMakingPrivateMethodCall("test");
        Assert.assertEquals("test test", result);
    }

}
```

maven dependencies are

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: what's the error? have you imported junit?

Comment: @leeor yes all import statements and dependencies are there

Comment: what version of junit? show the rest of the code

Comment: @leeor added dependencies of pom and i have also imported packages in class, with organize import and manually too

Comment: the error is on @Test annotation

Comment: show the full test class. are you using the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`?

Comment: Cuold you please post the error's stacktrace.

Answer (score 9):

When you see this error , it means you have a class name as “Test” in the same package.

[image]

Just rename that class name and it will work fine!!!!